# Can anyone help me in Deriving of functional dependencies and Normalizing tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, functional-dependencies

[image]I have created Restaurant e-r diagram and for my individual work, Can anyone help me inderiving of functional dependencies , Normalizing tables(BCNF form) and Construction of a database based on the obtained relations .

**Update**:
[image: ER diagram]

**I created relational model and normalized it to the 3NF:**
[image]

**And This is my oracle SQL code:**

```
create table restaurant(
    name varchar(20),
    city varchar(20) not null,
    contact_no char(15),
    constraint pk_name_restaurant primary key(name)
    );

create table contact_number(
    contact_no char(15),
    address varchar(50) not null,
    constraint pk_contact_no_contact_number primary key(contact_no)
    
);
create table cashier(
    cashier_id char(10)  ,
    cashier_name varchar(20) not null,
    constraint pk_chashierId_cashier primary key(cashier_id)

);

create table restaurant_has(
    name varchar(20),
    cashier_id char(10),
    constraint pk_restaurantHas primary key(name,cashier_id)
 
);

create table chef(
    chef_id char(10),
    chef_name varchar(20) not null,
    salary number(5,0),
    constraint pk_chefid_chef primary key(chef_id)
);

create table chef_works(
    name varchar(20) ,
    chef_id char(10),
    constraint pk_chefworks primary key(name,chef_id)
);


create table customer_order(
    order_no char(10),
    num_meals number(2,0),
    bill_no char(10) not null,
    constraint pk_orderno_order primary key(order_no)
);

create table chef_prepares(
    chef_id char(10),
    order_no char(10),
    constraint pk_chefprepares primary key(chef_id,order_no)
);

create table meal(
    meal_no char(10),
    quantity number(2,0),
    meal_price number(2,0),
    meal_title varchar(25) not null,
    order_no char(10) not null,
    constraint pk_orderno_meal primary key(meal_no)
);

create table meal_title(
    meal_title varchar(25),
    ingredients varchar(75) not null,
    constraint pk_mealtitle primary key(meal_title)
);

create table customer(
    cust_id char(10),
    cust_address varchar(50),
    cust_phone char(15) not null,
    constraint pk_custid_customer primary key(cust_id)
);

create table customer_phone(
    cust_phone char(15),
    cust_name varchar(20) not null,
    constraint pk_customerphone primary key(cust_phone) 
);

create table order_bill(
    bill_no char(10),
    price number(5,0) not null,
    bill_date date not null,
    cust_id char(10) not null,
    cashier_id char(10) not null,
    constraint pk_billno_orderbill primary key(bill_no)
);

alter table restaurant add constraint fk_contactNo_restaurant foreign key(contact_no) references contact_number(contact_no);

alter table restaurant_has add constraint fk_name_restauranthas foreign key(name) references restaurant(name);

alter table restaurant_has add constraint fk_cashierid_restauranthas foreign key(cashier_id) references cashier(cashier_id);

alter table chef_works add constraint fk_name_chefworks foreign key(name) references restaurant(name);

alter table chef_works add constraint fk_chefid_chefworks foreign key(chef_id) references chef(chef_id);

alter table chef_prepares add constraint fk_chefid_chefprepares foreign key(chef_id) references chef(chef_id);

alter table chef_prepares add constraint fk_chefid_chefprepares foreign key(chef_id) references chef(chef_id);

alter table customer_order add constraint fk_billno_customerorder foreign key(bill_no) references  order_bill(bill_no);

alter table meal add constraint fk_mealtitle_meal foreign key(meal_title) references meal_title(meal_title);

alter table meal add constraint fk_orderno_meal foreign key(order_no) references customer_order(order_no);

alter table customer add constraint fk_custphone_customer foreign key(cust_phone) references customer_phone(cust_phone);

alter table order_bill add constraint fk_custid_orderbill foreign key(cust_id) references customer(cust_id);

alter table order_bill add constraint fk_cashierid_orderbill foreign key(cashier_id) references cashier(cashier_id);
```

Comment: Hi - unfortunately that is probably too broad a question to get a useful response. If you show what you have managed to achieve on your own and then ask a focussed, specific question about a particular issue you are having trouble with then you are more likely to get a response

Comment: Hi, one of my questions is there have to be relations between bill and order?

Comment: Second one is in my Diagram order and meal are one to many relanshionship, Customer and order , customer and bill is also one to many is it true?

Comment: There is no right answer to any of your questions, its entirely up to your specific set of circumstances, the requirements you have, how you decide to model it, etc. For example, if a group of people are eating together you might have multiple customers per order; one person could pay the bill for the group or each person in the group could pay their share

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.  Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Not sure what everyone is complaining about, if you know how to read this type of ER diagram it’s actually pretty easy to answer this question.  The OP did make a couple of mistakes in the diagram, but they’re not hard to figure out.  There’s nothing at all “too broad” here, the diagram provides the necessary specs, it is a single question with a correct answer.  Moreover, many questions like this have been asked an answered here in the past.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The reason why everyone, apart from you, considered this question too broad is that the purpose of Stackoverflow is to get answers to specific, technical, coding challenges. The fact that you've had to write an "essay" in attempting to answer the question rather proves the point

Comment: @NickW This is incorrect.  First the OP did provide a specific question with a specific answer.  Second there is nothing in StackOverflow's rules or guidelines that indicates that short, trite, glib answers are better than detailed explanatory and educational answers.  Indeed, most of the most highly voted answers are what you have dismissed as "essays", I can provide examples if you are unfamiliar with them.  And finally, I did not *need* to provide a detailed explanation for this answer, I chose to provide it because I had the time and it made for a better answer.

Comment: And this is a single question, and questions of this type have historically been answered in this forum.  Is it a bit bigger than most? Yes, but that does not mean that no one should attempt to answer it.  It can always be answered *in part* by way of demonstrating how the OP could continue in that direction.  And folks who don't want to make that effort are not required to.  But that is very different from saying that the question should not have been asked or that no one should answer it.

Comment: typo: "... a specific question *which has* a specific answer."

Comment: And it certainly is not true that "*there is no right answer to any of your questions*".  There definitely are correct answers that cover most of what was asked.  I provided one version of a correct answer.

Comment: What is your 1 question given what? PS Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research or other effort re being stuck. Please see [ask], [Help], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers. After your initial version got answers you added diagrams & code that seem to be based on answers you got. That seems questionable. Don't change a question to incorporate answers, post a new question. Please do not insert EDITs/UPDATEs, edit your post to be the best presentation of your 1 specific question. [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an [Entity Relationship Model diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), which back in the day we also used to call a Chen diagram.  For some odd reason colleges and tutorials almost exclusively teach data modelling using this type of diagram model.  What's odd is that virtually no one in industry or practical DB development ever uses them, it is considered an entirely unnecessary and onerous intermediate step in data modelling and database design, we just go straight to tables, columns and relations modelling (which we call "ER Models/Diagrams" but are technically [IDEFX1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X) model diagrams, but again no one calls them that).

Consequently what everyone coming out of school or a tutorial calls an ER Diagram and what everyone in industry and practical use thinks is an ER diagram are completely different things.  Also, as you can see, many data folks with DB experience don't even know what a Chen diagram is or how to read one and so they are completely unaware that they are (almost) complete specs for the design of a database.  As such the question is not at all "too broad" or inspecific.  I myself had to learn how to read these diagram 20 years ago because I was interviewing so many college graduates at the time and this was the only diagramming/data-modelling technique that they knew.

I will walk through the process of reading and interpreting this diagram and explain how to turn that into Functional Dependencies and an (almost complete) data design.  This is essentially the same task as converting a Chen diagram to text form, and I will leave it in text form without making the IDEFX1 (table-relational) diagram (I don't really have a good tool for it now that I'm retired).  Datatypes are not specified here (which is normal for a Chen diagram) and although *technically* a formal relational data design does *NOT* require datatypes, practically speaking you do need them to finish your design and implementation.  Also, there appears to be several mistakes or omissions in your Diagram which I will call out as I get to them.

So let's start with the basics of how to read a Chen diagram:

[image]

Legend:

- The (blue) rectangles become tables which are Codd "relations" (*intra*-table).
- The ovals or "bubbles" are columns in the table they are attached to,
- Ovals with underlined text represent the primary key for the table they are attached to,
- The (blue) diamonds represent Chen relations (*inter*-table) that will usually become your Foreign Key constraints,
- The lines from a diamond (relation) to a rectangle (table) also indicate cardinality.  An arrow means a cardinality of one, while no arrow is means "many" (this actually varies a lot in different "styles" so I am guessing as to which style you are using for this).

So now we can go through the diagram, first looking at the tables and columns and derive the *intra*-table functional dependencies from them.  Intra-table functional dependencies go *from* the primary key columns *to* all of the other columns (if there are alternate keys then these would be additional functional dependencies)

***Tables*** Functional Dependencies:

- **Cashier:** Cashier_Id --> CashierName
- **Restaurant:** Name --> Address, ContactNo
- **Chef:** Chef_Id --> ChefName, Salary
- **Bill:** Bill_No --> Price, OrderDetail
- **Customer:** Cust_Id --> Cust_Name, Cust_Phone, Cust_Address
- **Meal:** Meal_No --> Meal_Title, Meal_Price, Description, Quantity
- **Order:** Order_No --> #Num_Meals(??)

I have marked the `#Num_Meals` column as questionable because it appears to be an aggregated field which are non-relational/denormalized and thus inappropriate in the data design (they are added much later in the application design/implementation, and usually as dynamic, not static elements).  But I will leave it in for clarity.

Now we are ready to look at the Chen relations to derive the *inter*-table functional dependencies:

***Relations:***

- **PaidTo**:  Bill --> Cashier
- **Pays**: Bill --> Customer
- **Places**: Order --> Customer
- **Contains**: Meal --> Order (*)
- **Prepare**: Order --> Chef (*)
- **Works**: Cashier --> Restaurant (*)
- **Has**: Chef --> Restaurant (*)

(*) -- A note about the last four relations (Contains, Prepare, Works and Has), none of them has a connection with an arrow on it which implies that they are supposed to represent a many-to-many relation which has a couple of problems.  First, Many-To-Many is not a valid relationship in relational data design and in practice requires the artificial creation of an intermediate "junction" table to change it from `A:many-to-many:B` into two relations between three tables: `A:many-to-one:J:one-to-many:B`.  The other problem is that it seems clear from the context (the meaning of the table names) that you can have many Meals for one Order, but never many Orders for one Meal and thus the diagram is clearly wrong on that one.

Therefore, to avoid getting into the complexity of Junction tables I have just assumed that the diagram is wrong for these relations and that there is supposed to be arrows from `<Contains>` to `[Order]` and from `<Prepare>` to `[Chef]`, etc.  If you know for certain that these are supposed to be Many-to-Many relationships then you will have to incorporate that.

Now all we need to do is to combine and reduce the two lists of functional dependencies so that there are no redundancies.  You can change the related-tables FDs into table-columns FDs simply by replacing the table names with the corresponding column names of their primary keys.  For instance, the PaidTo relation's `Bill --> Cashier` would become `Bill_No --> Cashier_Id`.  Once you have changed all of the FDs into table-column FDs, then you want to remove any redundancies by combining any FDs that have the same "key" on the left-hand side.  Thus, `Bill_No --> Cashier_Id` and `Bill_No --> Price, OrderDetail` would be combined into `Bill_No --> Price, OrderDetail, Cashier_Id`.

***Final Functional Dependencies***:

- **Cashier:** Cashier_Id --> CashierName, Restaurant(Name)
- **Restaurant:** Name --> Address, ContactNo
- **Chef:** Chef_Id --> ChefName, Salary, Restaurant(Name)
- **Bill:** Bill_No --> Price, OrderDetail, Cashier_Id, Cust_Id
- **Customer:** Cust_Id --> Cust_Name, Cust_Phone, Cust_Address
- **Meal:** Meal_No --> Meal_Title, Meal_Price, Description, Quantity, Order_No
- **Order:** Order_No --> #Num_Meals(??), Cust_Id, Chef_Id

*Warning, different people, teachers, instructors and tutorials may do this (reduction) differently and thus end up with a different final list.  You will have to review the rules that your course instructor expects and apply them here.*

Finally, we are are ready to do the Table and Relations implementation/design.  There is not enough information/context for me to do this all the way to BCNF for certain, but I can get it pretty close based on what we have above:

```
TABLE Restaurant
(   Name Primary Key,
    Address,
    ContactNo
)

TABLE Cashier
(   Cashier_Id Primary Key,
    CashierName ,
    Restaurant_Name FOREIGN KEY References Restaurant(Name)
)

TABLE Chef
(   Chef_Id Primary Key,
    ChefName,
    Salary,
    Restaurant_Name FOREIGN KEY References Restaurant(Name)
)

TABLE Bill
(   Bill_No Primary Key,
    Price,
    OrderDetail,
    Cashier_Id FOREIGN KEY References Cashier(Cashier_Id)
    Cust_Id FOREIGN KEY References Customer(Cust_Id)
)

TABLE Meal
(
    Meal_No Primary Key,
    Meal_Title,
    Meal_Price,
    Description,
    Quantity,
    Order_No FOREIGN KEY References Order(Order_No)
)

TABLE Order
(
    Order_No Primary Key,
    #Num_Meals (??),
    Cust_Id FOREIGN KEY References Customer(Cust_Id),
    Chef_Id FOREIGN KEY References Chef(Chef_Id)
)
```

Note that there are no datatypes below because none were provided in the diagram.  None of this will actually compile without specifying datatypes for each column.  Also, the word "Order" is a reserved keyword in almost all databases, so you may want to change the name of the Orders table to something like 'Order_" to avoid any problems (otherwise you will have to explicitly quote this name in all of the SQL that refers to it).

One last thing I will note: It seems like the Bill table should have a relation/reference to the Order table but it does not (the OrderDetail column does not do this according to your diagram).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I made some updates in my ER diagrams and tried to create a Relational Model  then normalized it 3NF (Added Images below my question), I also added oracle SQL code. Can you please check all of them? Is everything I did true??

Comment: @NailaBagir  I do not have as much time right now, and technically a full review would be another (new, different) question.  However, doing a quick review it does seem that you've address all of my questions and concerns correctly.  Please remember to upvote any answers that you found helpful and if and if any answered you question, then to mark one of them as the answer.

Comment: Oh okay ), Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is indeed "too broad a question".  (The shortest possible answer is "read everything ever written on the differences between conceptual modeling and formal logical modeling, and how to go from the former to the latter.".)  I can only provide a number of hints.

It seems like you use an E/R syntax where entities are rectangles and relationships are diamonds.  The ellipses indicate "properties" of the entities.  However, E/R is a ***conceptual*** modeling technique while normalization theory applies to ***formalized*** models in which everyting is represented as relations (***mathematical*** sense of the word).  So you need to worry about how you are going to make ***everything*** in this conceptual model represented as "relations with attributes".  Hint : for the entities, you seem to have them already, but what about the relationships (note carefully : relationSHIP is not the same thing as relation !!!).  For example, if a given cashier works 40% for one restaurant and 60% for another one, how are you going to represent that ?  Is that situation supposed to be supported ?

Then, it seems like you have already thought about identifiers, because you underlined them.  The thing that normalization theory is about, +-, is to facilitate the identification of ***all*** the keys that apply to a relation in the logical schema.  Look at your "restaurant" entity.  You seem to already have decided that, in FD terms, {Name} -> {Address, ContactNo}.  What you need to worry about is questions like "is it also the case that {ContactNo} -> {Name, Address} ?".  Or iow, "can it be the case that two distinct restaurants have the very same contact n° ?".

Further, look at the "OrderDetail" property in "Bill".  Formalizing to a logical model means you're going to have to decide on a data type for this property.  So what "data type" are you going to use ?  To my mind, the "detail" of an order is the ***entire list*** of items ordered, with their quantities ordered etc etc.  Is that something you are going to represent as a column in some table in your db ?  (I'm not implying to say that your model is ***wrong*** here.  Yes, orders have order details.  It's just that saying so remains at a very high level of abstraction that +- conflicts with the lower level of abstraction that you managed to achieve for the other entities.  By including that as a property, you are communicating that "it's there and I know it is there, but I still don't have a clue as to what it looks like".  And that calls for "then elaborate that first".  (Hint : you might find that actually there is also a relationship between "order" and "bill" because "bill" only gets created in the context of on order that was served.  This of course also means that you are going to have to formalize ***that*** relationship.)

I'm going to stop here.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. I made some updates in my ER Diagram (I added a picture under the previous image). Do I have to add attribute (for example ,work_hours) to the cashier?